# ¿Cómo geolocalizar tweets en R?

Tags: r, geolocalización

Buen día , tengo un pequeño problema en mi código. Básicamente quiero geolocalizar los tweets que logro obtener:

```
searchTerm <- "#sismo" # termino de busqueda
searchResults <- searchTwitter(searchTerm, n = 100) # Búsqueda
tweetFrame <- twListToDF(searchResults) # Creamos data frame

userInfo <- lookupUsers(tweetFrame$screenName) #Información del usuario (Nombre)
userFrame <- twListToDF(userInfo) # Creamos data frame 

locatedUsers <- !is.na(userFrame$location) #Mantenga sólo los usuarios con información de ubicación
locations <- geocode(userFrame$location[locatedUsers]) #API de adivinar Aproximada lat / lon de datos de ubicación textual.
locations
```

El problema es que trato de ejecutar la linea `locations <- geocode` y me arroja el error:

```
Error: no se pudo encontrar la función "geocode".
```

Cuando en un principio si se ejecutaba. ¿Alguien podrá ayudarme?.

Comment: No tienes la función `geocode` en memoria, y en `library(twitteR)` esa función no existe. Es posible que hayas ejecutado el código que contiene esa función antes, y ahora se te olvido hacerlo. Sabes donde esta `geocode <- function(arg1 ...){ .. }`?

Comment: Buenas , gracias por responder  y me disculpo por postear tarde, quiero tratar de hacer algo parecido , así que la parte de geolocalizar es la que no logro. No sé si alguien tiene otra manera de hacerlo. Saludos y gracias.. 


 https://gist.github.com/dsparks/4329876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no estas cargando el paquete `dismo` el cual contiene la función `geocode`. Si sigues el [gist de dsparks](https://gist.github.com/dsparks/4329876) al pie de la letra te va funcionar (casi) todo porque el autor incluyó un pedacito de código para instalar y cargar los paquetes necesarios:

```r
doInstall <- TRUE
toInstall <- c("twitteR", "dismo", "maps", "ggplot2")
if(doInstall){install.packages(toInstall, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")}
lapply(toInstall, library, character.only = TRUE)
```

Un poco mas abajo, en la regla despues de definir `locations` dice `with(locations, plot(lon, lat))`. Esto hay que corregir porque no hay columnas llamadas `lon` y `lat`. Verifica usando `colnames`

```
> colnames(locations)
[1] "originalPlace"    "interpretedPlace" "longitude"       
[4] "latitude"         "xmin"             "xmax"            
[7] "ymin"             "ymax"             "uncertainty"
```

## Crear el grafico

Corrigiendo `lon` y `lat` a `longitude` y `latitude`, [el código](https://gist.github.com/dsparks/4329876) debe correr sin problemas. Lo encuentras corregido aquí abajo para que lo copies y pegues. Pero primero verifica que has instalado y cargado los paquetes requeridos y que has autenticado con el API de Twitter (mira mas abajo para instrucciones).

```r
searchTerm <- "#rstats"
searchResults <- searchTwitter(searchTerm, n = 1000)  # Gather Tweets 
tweetFrame <- twListToDF(searchResults)  # Convert to a nice dF

userInfo <- lookupUsers(tweetFrame$screenName)  # Batch lookup of user info
userFrame <- twListToDF(userInfo)  # Convert to a nice dF

locatedUsers <- !is.na(userFrame$location)  # Keep only users with location info

locations <- geocode(userFrame$location[locatedUsers])  # Use amazing API to guess
# approximate lat/lon from textual location data.
with(locations, plot(longitude, latitude))

worldMap <- map_data("world")  # Easiest way to grab a world map shapefile

zp1 <- ggplot(worldMap)
zp1 <- zp1 + geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),  # Draw map
                       colour = gray(2/3), lwd = 1/3)
zp1 <- zp1 + geom_point(data = locations,  # Add points indicating users
                        aes(x = longitude, y = latitude),
                        colour = "RED", alpha = 1/2, size = 1)
zp1 <- zp1 + coord_equal()  # Better projections are left for a future post
zp1 <- zp1 + theme_minimal()  # Drop background annotations
print(zp1)
```

## Autenticar con el API de Twitter

Para alguien que lea esto y no logre conectar con Twitter a travez de twitterR, es necesario primero hacer la autorización con al API de Twitter. Registrate y crea una nueva aplicacion en https://apps.twitter.com/. Alli genera el token y copia los siguientes datos, y pon tus valores donde estan las xxx:

```
Consumer_Key <- "xxx"
Consumer_Secret <-  "xxx"
Access_Token <- "xxx"
Access_Token_Secret <-  "xxx"
```

Con eso estas listo para conectarte:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(Consumer_Key, Consumer_Secret, Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret)
```

Y puedes correr el código arriba.

Comment: Buen día, perfecto ya logre verificar todo y en efecto es como comentaste, adicionalmente la parte de api twitter ya la tenia, pero se agradece todo el tiempo que tomaste para explicarme. Estoy actualmente trabajándola para hacerla por medio de shiny y montarla en shinyapps.io. Gracias por toda la ayuda prestada.